# Unable to make a foreign key in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I try to create a relationship between tables `BUYER` and `COUNTRY` (`NEGARA`) in SQL Server 2012 but always error when I try to save my diagram.

Here's the message :

> 'NEGARA' table saved successfully
>   'BUYER' table
>   Unable to create relationship 'FK_BUYER_NEGARA'.
>   The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_BUYER_NEGARA". The conflict occurred in database "DBXYZ", table "dbo.NEGARA", column 'KD_NEGARA'.

I check my table and sure that the data type and the content is similar. I forced to save my diagram by make the Check Existing Data On Creation as a NO. Please help me to solve this problem because evidently it has affected my ETL process on SSIS.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The message is clear: your table `BUYER` contains **invalid values** in the column that is involved in the foreign key you're trying to establish - values that are **not** present in the referenced table (`NEGARA`). You need to **fix this** (by updating or setting NULL) those "offending" values. You cannot create your FK constraint before you've fixed this situation

Comment: It's a good thing you are adding a constraint since but you already have existing data that violates it. Although you could create the foreign key with the `NOCKECK` option, it would be better to fix the data by either adding the missing rows to the related table or deleting/updating the referencing data.

Comment: Find out what values in your foreign key column don't exist in your Primary Key column. As we don't have you table DDL you'll need to replace the appropriate object names: `SELECT FT.ForeignKey_Column FROM ForeignTable FT LEFT JOIN PrimaryTable PT WHERE FT.ForeignKey_Column = PT.PrimaryKey_Column WHERE PT.PrimaryKey_Column IS NULL;`